# Jenkins Running defended stages in serial order from array

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I currently I got an array with defined build stages that runn in parallel

```
def build_stages =[:]

build_stages["one"]={echo "one"}
build_stages["two"]={echo "two"}
build_stages["three"]={echo "three"}

parallel build_stages
```

Obviously  those stages running in parallel

Is there an syntax option that can allow to run those stage as serial run?

```
build_stages["one"] --> build_stages["two"] --> build_stages["three"]
```

Comment: "Apparently"? `parallel build_stages` is explicitly asking them to run in parallel.

Comment: @MaratC **Obviously

Comment: I tried also followed
build_stages.each(){ it }
also without expected result

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you need to create stages dynamically? Usually pipelines are executed in serial order if not explicitly implemented

Comment: @MichaelKemmerzell to simplify I got stages stored in  build_stages, I want to rub them one by one

Comment: `build_stages.each { it -> it.call() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by @Patrice M
build_stages.each { it -> it.call() }

Answer (score 0):

For me `build_stages.each { it -> it.call() }` did not work and was getting exception in logs:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.AbstractMap$SimpleImmutableEntry.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(long, int)
```

Correct solution will be to call the stored value of each key in the Map, like this:

`build_stages.each {key, value -> value()}`